# Trivial MySQL Query: WHERE (...) AND (...)

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

I must be having a case of the Fridays... Suppose I have the following tables and data:

```
+------------+
| Park       |
+------------+
| Cape Cod   |
| Blue Ridge |
| Ice Age    |
+------------+

+--------+
| Tag    |
+--------+
| Biking |
| Skiing |
+--------+

+---------------------+
| ParkTags            |
+------------+--------+
| Cape Cod   | Biking |
| Blue Ridge | Hiking |
| Ice Age    | Biking |
| Ice Age    | Hiking |
+------------+--------+
```

In other words, parks are stored in one table, tags on the other, and a third table links one or more tags to a park.

What I'm trying to do is select one or more tags and return all parks that have ALL tags. From the information above, the tags are associated with the parks as follows:

Biking:
Cape Cod
Ice Age

Hiking:
Blue Ridge
Ice Age

Biking AND Hiking:
Ice Age

My question is, what am I doing wrong with my query? What I'm trying to get is all parks that have the tags Biking AND Hiking.

```
# My query so far

SELECT
    Park.name as Park,
    Tag.name as Tag

FROM
    ParkTags
    JOIN Park ON Park.id = ParkTags.fk_park_id
    JOIN Tag  ON Tag.id  = ParkTags.fk_tag_id

WHERE
    Tag.name = 'Biking' AND Tag.name = 'Hiking'

ORDER BY
     Park.name
```

My expected output is to get Ice Age park only. Running that query returns zero results. If I change the AND for an OR in the condition, the result is all three parks.

Thanks.

Comment: all conditions specified in where clause are matched against each row to select. this join will generate two rows containing 'Ice Age' one with Biking and one with Hiking, and none of both will have Tag.name = 'Biking' AND Tag.name='Hiking' at the same time.

Comment: I am confused by the duplicate use of `Park`, both as a field name and as a table name.  I doubt it causes any confusion for sql, but it should be revised.

Comment: @wallyk This is a simplified example. The actual table name different, as is the field name. It's just for simplicity in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first problem I see is that you want to return ANY parks that have ALL tags, but you are using a where clause to specify the tags you want returned... As someone above mentioned, you're not going to have a row match both criteria at the same time (the AND operator), but I think any kind of where clause on the tag column would brake your requirement anyway, so that's moot.

Here's your table definitions

```
parks
---------
id
name

tag
------
id
name

parktags
-------
id
fk_parks_id
fk_tags_id
```

I'd probably start with a left join on the parktags table, something like this

```
SELECT p.name, t.name 
FROM   parktags PT
          LEFT JOIN parks P ON p.id = pt.fk_parks_id
          LEFT JOIN tag T ON t.id = pt.fk_tags_id
```

That'll give you all parktags, with matching parks and tags. Now we need to return only the ones that have multiple entries on parktags. Let's try something like this

```
SELECT p.name, t.name 
FROM   parktags PT
          LEFT JOIN parks P ON p.id = pt.fk_parks_id
          LEFT JOIN tag T ON t.id = pt.fk_tags_id
GROUP BY pt.fk_parks_id
HAVING COUNT(pt.fk_tags_id) > 1
```

HAVING works just like WHERE, except that HAVING allows you to use aggregates for the condition check, but WHERE does not. We could have used a subselect in a where clause, nothing particularly wrong with that, but subselects require their own, separate execution plan and that is more costly than a join.

I don't have a console in front of me, so I can't test this, I'm sure there will be something wrong with it. You may have to play with the HAVING and GROUP BY clauses some more to get it just right, but it'll be something along those lines. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: I just re-read leigh's answer and realize we did pretty much the same thing. We must be onto something here... :)

Comment: Perfect. This looks pretty good. I won't be back in the office until Monday, but I'm sure I can take it from here with this info. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marciolsf - Yep, but you explained how it works, which is better than just posting code :) Though if the number of tags varies, I would switch the HAVING clause to:  `HAVING COUNT(theID) = {desired number}` rather than `HAVING COUNT(theID) > 1`. Just so you get the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Tag.name cannot have the values 'Biking' and 'Hiking' at the same time.

Comment: True. But it would be helpful to show the correct syntax as well :).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.name, 
       group_concat(t.name)

FROM Park p
JOIN ParkTags pt ON pt.fk_park_id = p.id
JOIN Tag t       ON pt.fk_tag_id  = t.id

WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 

    FROM ParkTags pt 
    JOIN Tag t ON t.id = pt.fk_tag_id 

    WHERE t.name in ('Biking','Hiking') 
    AND pt.fk_park_id=p.id
) = 2

GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a slight adaptation of [Nesim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10358705/104223):

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS Name list
FROM Park p
        INNER JOIN ParkTags pt ON pt.fk_park_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN Tag t ON t.id = pt.fk_tag_id
WHERE   t.name in ('Biking','Hiking')
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Parks.Name
FROM
    Park 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ParkTags b WHERE b.Tag = 'Hiking' AND b.Name = Park.Name)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ParkTags c WHERE c.Tag = 'Biking' AND c.Name = Park.Name)
```

Something like that?
You're checking for the existence of matching tags
This will not scale well....